# assign bash array values to variables

Tags: bash

I have a file with list of disks and their serial numbers in separate lines.  The data is consistent through the file formatted like this:

```
Disk hostname disk              /proc/cds/cdd/disks/csd1
Disk hostname disk              serial: NAGYNLGX
Disk hostname disk              /proc/cds/cdd/disks/csd10
Disk hostname disk              serial: NAGY85MX
```

I am trying to grab the data from the first of two lines /proc/cds/cdd/disks/cds1 and place the next line's serial number after it on the same line such that it would be formatted this way:

```
/proc/cds/cdd/disks/csd1  NAGYNLGX
/proc/cds/cdd/disks/cds10 NAGY85MX
```

I tried using an array to read in all the file output and then assign variables with the values in a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray a < rec20.txt

total=${#a[*]}

for (( i=0; i<=$(( $total -1 )); i++ ))
do
let b=i+1
#     echo -n "${a[$i]} "|awk '{print $4}'; echo -n "${a[$b]} "|awk '{print $5}'
#     echo -e "${a[$i]} "|awk '{print $4}'\t; echo -e "${a[$b]} "|awk '{print $5}'\n
#     set var1= echo "${a[$i]} " |awk '{print $4}'
#     set var2= echo "${a[$b]} " |awk '{print $5}'
#     var1=printf '%s\t' "${a[$i]} "|awk '{print $4}'
#     var2=printf '%s\n' "${a[$b]} "|awk '{print $5}'
echo -e "${a[$i]} "|awk '{print $4}'\t
echo -e "${a[$b]} "|awk '{print $5}'\n
echo "var1 is $var1 var2 is $var2"
let i++
done
```

Comment: Shell assignments are `var=value` to do that with the output from a command is `var=$(command)`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily using `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR%2{s=$NF; next} {print s, $NF}' rec20.txt
/proc/cds/cdd/disks/csd1    NAGYNLGX
/proc/cds/cdd/disks/csd10   NAGY85MX
```

btw to read file data correctly into BASH array you need to use `-t` option i.e.

```
readarray -t a < rec20.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This here will read the file (file.txt) and parse it how you wanted:

```
read -a lines <<< `cat file.txt | sed -e "s/.* //"` 

for (( i=0; i<${#lines[*]}; i+=2 )); do
    myArray+=("${lines[i]}  ${lines[i+1]}")
done
```

The first line reads the file and passes it into "sed" which trims off everything after the last space. So the file contents will be changed from what you posted to this:

```
/proc/cds/cdd/disks/csd1
NAGYNLGX
/proc/cds/cdd/disks/csd10
NAGY85MX
```

I then just looped through all the lines, and every other line I appended "myArray" to hold the current line and the next line put together.